# JetBrains BUG: How to make JetBrains IDEs never ever cache directories into memory?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I have very big project and I am tired JetBrains always shows me wrong directory content in various dialogs.

Is it possible to turn this "feature" forever? Let is show exactly what is it on disk all the time?

Pressing `Reload From Disk` / `Refresh` is not a solution, because it works in 70% cases only and also with a significant delay.

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug report for jetbrains?

Comment: I think you should check [BugTracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) and find an answer or make a new one.

Comment: What if you try to use NATIVE file chooser for your OS? AFAIK it should use it already on Mac; for Windows you can use `de.win.file.chooser.native` Registry entry (`Help | Find Action... | Registry...`).